# how to let notepad++ console outputs be colorful

Tags: notepad++, nppexec

how to let notepad++ console outputs be colorful
for example:
I run some nppexec script and output text like this in console

[resource] => Resource id #574
[cursor] => 2
[EOF] => 1
[fields] => Array

the outputs are all black.but I want to let [...] to be green. how to set ?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to setup filters. Press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> then you can setup wildcard matches & define a colour, E.g. mine is;

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You need to save the file first and in the [Save As] dialog, choose the format that matches the text (for example, C++/Visual Basic/Java/... etc).

Comment: That's for an opened file - the question is about NPP's console output.